# Symfony 7: How to Bypass Authentication for Login Route?

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, authorization, custom-authentication

I have a Symfony 7 project where I'm implementing custom authentication logic for the login route (/api/login). I have a login method in my controller that handles user login and generates a token based on the provided name. Additionally, I've created a custom AuthenticationListener class that implements AuthenticatorInterface to handle authentication for other routes.

Here's a summary of the relevant code:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Attribute\AsEventListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AuthenticatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;



class AuthenticationListener implements AuthenticatorInterface
{

    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        $route = $request->attributes->get('_route');
        return str_starts_with($route, 'api_');
    }

    #[AsEventListener(event: 'kernel.request')]
    public function authenticate(RequestEvent|Request $event): Passport
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        // Check if the request is for the login route
        if ($request->attributes->get('_route') === 'login') {

            return new Passport();
        }


        if (!$request->headers->has('Authorization')) {
            throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('Unauthorized', 'Authorization header is missing');
        }

        $key = $request->headers->get('Authorization');

        if (!$key) {
            throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('Unauthorized', 'Authorization header is missing');
        }

        $decryptedName = $this->decrypt($key);

        if (!$decryptedName) {
            throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('Unauthorized', 'Invalid or expired token');
        }

        // Create a UserBadge for other routes
        $userBadge = new UserBadge($decryptedName, function ($username) {
            return null;
        });

        return new Passport($userBadge);
    }


    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        return new Response('Authenticated Successfully', Response::HTTP_OK);
    }


    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {
        return new Response('Unauthorized', Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    private function decrypt($string): string
    {
        // Decrypt the authorization token using your decryption method
        $secret_key = $_ENV['APP_SECRET']; // Ensure you have APP_KEY set in your environment variables
        $key = openssl_digest($secret_key, 'SHA256', TRUE);
        $c = base64_decode($string);
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher = "AES-128-CBC");
        $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
        $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len = 32);
        $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen + $sha2len);
        $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        //        dd($original_plaintext);
        $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, true);
        if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) {
            return $original_plaintext;
        }
        return ''; // Return an empty string if decryption fails
    }


    public function createToken(Passport $passport, string $firewallName): TokenInterface
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method should not be called for stateless authentication.');
    }
}
```

```
class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }


    #[Route('/api/login', name: 'login', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function login(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        // Retrieve the request data
        $requestData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        // Ensure the required fields are provided
        if (!isset($requestData['name'])) {
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Name field is required'], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        $name = $requestData['name'];

        // Encrypt the name
        $encryptedName = $this->encrypt($name);

        // Generate a token based on the encrypted name
        $token = $this->generateToken($encryptedName);

        // Return the token to the client
        return new JsonResponse(['token' => $token]);
    }

    private function encrypt(string $name): string
    {
        $secretKey = $_ENV['APP_SECRET'];
        $key = openssl_digest($secretKey, 'SHA256', TRUE);
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher = "AES-128-CBC");
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
        $ciphertextRaw = openssl_encrypt($name, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertextRaw, $key, true);
        $output = base64_encode($iv . $hmac . $ciphertextRaw);

        return $output;
    }

    private function generateToken(string $encryptedName): string
    {
        // Generate a token based on the encrypted name
        return hash('sha256', $encryptedName);
    }
```

Despite my efforts, I'm encountering challenges bypassing authentication for the login route and ensuring proper authentication for other routes. I've experimented with different configurations, but I keep receiving errors related to missing or invalid authorization headers.

Could someone provide guidance on how to correctly implement custom authentication logic for the login route while ensuring authentication for other routes remains intact? Any insights, code examples, or configuration suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
security:
password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        lazy: true
        stateless: true
        custom_authenticators:
            - App\EventListener\AuthenticationListener
    api_login:
        pattern: ^/api/login
        stateless: true

access_control:
    - { path: '^/api/login', roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: '^/', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

**update**
I have updated the security.yml and customauthenticator.php but I receive this error "   "title": "An error occurred",
"status": 401,
"detail": "Full authentication is required to access this resource.",
"class": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",:

```
security:
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            stateless: true
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\CustomAuthenticator
        api_login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: false # Change stateless to false for stateful authentication

    access_control:
        - { path: '^/api/login', roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: '^/', roles: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN] }
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Exception;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AuthenticatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;

use App\Entity\User; // Assuming your User entity is in the App\Entity namespace

class CustomAuthenticator implements AuthenticatorInterface
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        return $request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST)
            && $request->getRequestUri() === '/api/login';
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $requestData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        if (!isset($requestData['name'])) {
            throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('Invalid credentials', 'Required field "name" is missing');
        }

        $name = $requestData['name'];

        try {
            $decryptedName = $this->decrypt($name);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('Invalid credentials', 'Invalid or tampered token');
        }

        $user = $this->loadUser($decryptedName);

        $userBadge = new UserBadge($decryptedName, function ($name) {
            return $this->loadUser($name);
        });

        return new Passport($userBadge);
    }

    private function loadUser(string $name): ?UserInterface
    {
        return $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['name' => $name]);
    }

    private function decrypt($string): string
    {
        // Decrypt the authorization token using your decryption method
        $secret_key = $_ENV['APP_SECRET']; // Ensure you have APP_KEY set in your environment variables
        $key = openssl_digest($secret_key, 'SHA256', TRUE);
        $c = base64_decode($string);
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher = "AES-128-CBC");
        $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
        $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len = 32);
        $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen + $sha2len);
        $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        //        dd($original_plaintext);
        $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, true);
        if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) {
            return $original_plaintext;
        }
        return ''; // Return an empty string if decryption fails
    }


    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        return new Response('Authenticated Successfully', Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {
        return new Response('Unauthorized', Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    public function createToken(Passport $passport, string $firewallName): TokenInterface
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method should not be called for stateless authentication.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Use access control to authorize your login route to PUBLIC_ACCESS

Comment: You configured your login path on a different firewall (`api_login`), that's the reason your Listener is not reacting. I would advice removing the `api_login` firewall. If you require a different firewall for the login, you should set `security: false` for that one

Comment: tnx a lot your suggestion was helpful now I have issue with decoding the token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your login requires no authorization, your access control should allow public access:

```yaml
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    # ...
    access_control:
        - { path: '^/api/login', roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: '^/', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY } # As per Martin Komischke comment
```

Read more about [allowing unsecured access](https://symfony.com/doc/7.x/security.html#allowing-unsecured-access-i-e-anonymous-users)

Also your Authenticator is somewhat mixed with an EventListener.

Try this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AuthenticatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;

class CustomAuthenticator implements AuthenticatorInterface
{

    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        return $request->headers->has('Authorization');
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $key = $request->headers->get('Authorization');

        $decryptedName = $this->decrypt($key);

        if (!$decryptedName) {
            throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('Unauthorized', 'Invalid or expired token');
        }

        // Create a UserBadge for other routes
        $userBadge = new UserBadge($decryptedName, function ($username) {
            return null;
        });

        return new Passport($userBadge);
    }


    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        return new Response('Authenticated Successfully', Response::HTTP_OK);
    }


    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {
        return new Response('Unauthorized', Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    private function decrypt($string): string
    {
        // Decrypt the authorization token using your decryption method
        $secret_key = $_ENV['APP_SECRET']; // Ensure you have APP_KEY set in your environment variables
        $key = openssl_digest($secret_key, 'SHA256', TRUE);
        $c = base64_decode($string);
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher = "AES-128-CBC");
        $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
        $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len = 32);
        $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen + $sha2len);
        $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        //        dd($original_plaintext);
        $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, true);
        if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) {
            return $original_plaintext;
        }
        return ''; // Return an empty string if decryption fails
    }
}
```

Please note the namespace and class name have changed, according to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/7.x/security/custom_authenticator.html)

Some changes:

- `supports` should not check for paths, that should be defined in your `security.yaml`
- `authenticate` had check that have been replaced by using the `supports` correctly

Comment: That is what I suggest too. 
Plus the other routes are configured to require ROLE_USER:

`- { path: ^/.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }`

Keep in mind the api route is above the general route. 
The access control list is "worked through" from top to bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I applied your suggestions, but still facing the same error"<!-- Authorization header is missing (401 Unauthorized) -->". Any further advice?

Comment: now I have this error     "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10",
    "title": "An error occurred",
    "status": 401,
    "detail": "Full authentication is required to access this resource.", I change the security.yaml file for different role access "     access_control:
        - { path: '^/api/login', roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: '^/', roles: ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'] }

Comment: the problem here I am facing is that the requests won't even reach the customauthenticator class and its authenticate method.

Comment: Based on your input, your request should have an Authorization header to get through the `supports`. If possible check your Profiler, it should provide security details for your request

Comment: I have updated the code and shared the changes plz give me your opinion.

Comment: Please read the documentation, right now you are mixing a UserProvider with an Authenticator. Since you are fetching your user from the database through Doctrine  you can just use the [Entity User Provider](https://symfony.com/doc/7.x/security/user_providers.html#security-entity-user-provider). Also check out the documentation about [Authenticators](https://symfony.com/doc/7.x/security/custom_authenticator.html), your `supports` is way too specific. Please provide information about how you want to authenticate your users, right now every update you give is a different scenario